# If-Else in a th:each statement in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

What I want is an if-else in a th:each statement in Thymeleaf.

`If currentSkill != null`, then show table with content, else 'You don't have any skills'

This is the code without the if/else:

```
<div th:each="skill : ${currentSkills}">
    <table>
         <tr><td th:text="${skill.name}"/></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<div  th:if="${currentSkills != null}">
    <table>
         <tr th:each="skill : ${currentSkills}"><td th:text="${skill.name}"/></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div th:if="${currentSkills == null}">
   You don't have any skills
</div>
```

If `currentSkills` is a list, you can use the `#lists` utility like so (which is more correct than the above code since it also takes into account the possibility where the object is not null but is empty):

```
 <div  th:if="!${#lists.isEmpty(currentSkills)}">
    <table>
         <tr th:each="skill : ${currentSkills}"><td th:text="${skill.name}"/></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(currentSkills)}">
   You don't have any skills
</div>
```

You could do the same if `currentSkills` is an array by just replacing `#lists` with `#arrays`.

Note that in both cases `isEmpty()` returns true whether the object is null or has zero items.

Comment: Tnx so much! The second solution was the one I needed.

Comment: th:unless is another option to prevent the !

Comment: so how do you do it on a per-item basis in the `th:each` ?

Comment: @mmcrae Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: My goal was to iterate over a list of objects, and if an object's property in that list == "a" for example, display "X", else display "Y", and do that for each object in the list

Comment: You can add a `th:if="${skill.a == 'whatever'}` like construct inside the `th:each`

Comment: @geoand using this approach would mean, the expression `${#lists.isEmpty(currentSkills)}` is computed twice. Would prefer to avoid this.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal You could easily store the result of the expression in local variable using `th:with`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<div  th:if="${!currentSkills.isEmpty()}">
    <table>
         <tr th:each="skill : ${currentSkills}"><td th:text="${skill.name}"/></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```