# Thymeleaf - Using same table for New and Edit

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to use the same html table for "New" Person and "Edit" person. For Person's contact(s) I am using a ContactDTO. Now I want to make use of the same template, same table in the form. Now this situation is very close (but different) to these two SO threads - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062218/how-to-do-a-if-else-in-thymeleaf-inside-a-loop-that-populate-a-table) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737836/if-else-in-a-theach-statement-in-thymeleaf).

From my controller I am setting "person" and "contactDto" as 'null' conditionally.

I have tried this (rather I dont have a clue what to do):

```
<tr th:fragment="contacts" th:if="${contactDto == null}" th:each="contact,rowStat : ${person.contactList} ? ${contactDto.getContacts()}">
```

With above expression I get this (obvious) exception:

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "contactDto.getContacts()"
```

How can I use these two model attributes in same th:each alternatively depending what comes as null?